# How to extract from element information about dictionary

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

I am working in silenium with Python.
Here attached the png where it is pointed out , what element I want to exctract:
[image]

In order to achieve my goal, I am using the following code:

```
el=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.hidden_info")
```

len of el is coincide the number of elemens That I want to extract, but for examle when I write `el[0].text` output is empty

Comment: el is just a list of elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value from hidden element use `element.get_attribute("textContent")`

```
el=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.hidden_info")
print(el[0].get_attribute("textContent"))
```

Reference link here [textContent](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_textcontent.asp)